# Syntax highlighting for Python in vim stopped working correctly

Tags: python, vim, syntax-highlighting

At certain time when I open `vim` editor with `Python` syntax highlighting is not working correctly.
Particularly I noticed that syntax highlighting is working partially. Everything is black, instead of comments (blue) and strings (red)

I'm afraid I have deleted something in the `$HOME/.vim` directory in the past.

So far, I tried:

to download [`python.vim`](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=790) and copied it to `$HOME/.vim/syntax` and I copied this new version to `/usr/share/vim/vim73/syntax/` as well.

In my `.vimrc` file there are still lines.

```
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on
```

So, I think there is no change in my `.vimrc` file.

It's worth noting that `TagBar` plugin for `Python` files is not working too.

Do you know how to repair it without reinstalling the whole environment, all plugins etc.?

Comment: It's important to backup your `.vimrc` regularly

Comment: We don't know anything about the previous working state and we don't know anything about the current non-working state. How do you think are we going to help you?

Comment: try this:

`https://github.com/SivaCn/vim-as-a-python-ide` and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YhqsjUUHj6g

Comment: @romainl I tried to be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you make a fresh one!

Try:

```
https://github.com/SivaCn/vim-as-a-python-ide
```

and

```
www.youtube.com/watch?v=YhqsjUUHj6g
```